# Integrating my web application with Magento

Tags: magento, e-commerce, magento-1.7

I have created a web application in PHP, Ajax, HTML5. It is ready and working perfectly. Now I want to integrate it with magento. In the application, when user clicks buy now an image is saved in a folder on the server.

I have just started using magento. There are two ways in my mind to implement the functionality,

1. Navigate the user from magento products page to my application page and when user clicks buy now button on my page it will be the add to cart functionality at the back end. And i will send the image name that is randomly generated and append it into the comments of product that admin can see.
2. Make my app a magento custom plugin. Add my HTML, css, js, php files within magento and use my app as an internal magento application.

So, i need suggestions, comments,  ideas or anything that can help me.

As I have just started with magento and I don't have any experience with e-commerce. So, my question might be showing in experience.

Answer (score 0):

Try to learn [Magento API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html)  it can be integrated with all your apps.